# Need to communicate both ways between my app and Navigation app

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on an app (in Xamarin, but anything you can do with androidstudio, you can do with Xamarin) that gives coordinates to the Navigation app like so:

```
var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?z=23");
var mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, geoUri);
StartActivity(mapIntent);
```

I've been scouring the web for info on how to do this, but from what I understand, this is a one-way street so to speak. There's no communication back to the original app after this point. What I need to do is send location pings back to the original app to send to the server. Xamarin has some documentation on how to do this with background services (though I may comment later asking for help with that if I can't figure it out). The tricky part is that once the user gets close enough to where they're going, the server is going to send the original app some updated coordinates and I need the navigation app to redirect to the updated coordinates. Is this at all possible and how might I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by app? What entity it is? Activity? Different separate android apps (processes)?

Comment: *If* the `Activity` is in an external app your calling and it supports `StartActivityForResult` then you can get a one time "answer" from that app/activity. But if you are looking for a "live two-way communication" that would only be supported if that external app supports it (via Broadcasts, Service intents/callbacks, etc...)...  It *sounds* like you are need to implement a Service that monitor Location changes, Xamarin has plenty of guides and samples: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/  https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Location/

Comment: @yosriz The app is an activity.

Comment: @SushiHangover I've never worked with services before, but I'll keep looking at those guides. Do you have any idea what _kind_ of service I should use? Bound? Intent? Started? Hybrid?

Comment: @GeoffL For Geo location services look at  : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/

Comment: can you elaborate on your app architecture? so do you have 2 activities? or you just need the UI (activity) to get and update locations with a server, I think it is crucial to understand the 2 components play role here in order to suggest a solution

Comment: So my app is just a bunch of simple activities. One activity gets coordinates from a server and contains the code I posted above to open a navigation app and direct the user to those coordinates. I didn't write the navigation app, it's just whatever navigation app the user wants to use (google maps,waze, uber, whatever...). It sounds like I need to start a service to run in the background to send periodic location updates back to the server. The tricky part is getting the navigation app to receive updated location coordinates and navigate to those coordinates.

Comment: I suppose i could just have a notification pop up that says "Hey! the location has been updated, click here to redirect".